# Custom responses — Google Home

Tags: google-home

I have a a web server up that listens on a particular URL and returns a unique response based upon a bunch of criteria.

For example (fake domain):

myserver.com/cgi-bin/nextslot

returns

"Hello, the next slot is at 2:00pm"

The response can be JSON or html or whatever.

What I want to do is hook this up to Google Home so that I can ask google "when is the next slot" and it calls my web server and reads out the response.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible by writing what is known as a [Google Assistant Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

There are some tools to make writing actions a little easier such as [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/) or the others mentioned in some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034431/can-i-deploy-an-app-to-google-assistant-without-using-googles-ai-platform-api)